# android lanuch unknown apk applications from command line

Tags: android

i'm trying for a while to lunch apk apps, from adb.
i know it's possible to open well known application like browser(am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity) which you know there's
main activity.
but what about other application which you don't know their's main activity, is there a way to get the main activity (or the activity's list) from adb, and than run the appilcation from adb as well??
i know it's possible using PackageManager() class, but i need to run it from command line(adb) and i have only the apk file.

thank's 
David Barns

Answer (score 0):

adb -e install "package.apk"

This will install and launch the application on emulator.

Comment: thank's for the fast replay, but i have the app already install on my emulator, i just need to run it(i dont know the main activity).

Comment: Check this 
http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/run-android-application-from-command.html

Comment: that's only possible by making reverse engineer to the apk file and open the manifest.xml file to get the package name and the activity class. but you need to pull the application from the emulator to the computer, do reverse engineer, check the activity and package